# My wife is stuck in a wall, can I save her?

Tags: xbox-360, fable-2

My wife, Lady Gray, is "stuck in a wall" in Fairfax Gardens, our Marital Home.  I can't actually see her, but the glowing trail leads me to the guard house (on the left when facing Fairfax manor) when I set my family as my target.  Is there any hope?

I've started a new approach.  I'm slowly trying to make my wife less happy with me.  I've reduced her allowance. Soon I'll try to downgrade the furniture (I have never tried to do this in Fairfax Castle).

I don't want to go too fast and just find her gone.  I'll post my progress.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I had this happen with a chicken once. Near the end of the game, when you're kicking chickens into a coop, one got stuck inside a wall. Saving and quitting didn't help - the beast was still firmly stuck.

An **oddly-aimed kick** solved my problem, but that's only because a chicken is an object that you can physically apply force to. You may not be so lucky with your wife. Try **Force Push** or something similar to give her a nice strong blast out the other side.

If you find that you can't physically move her, then there's not much you can do. After saving, quitting and resetting the game 10 or 20 times, if she's still stuck in the wall... it's likely permanent. Enjoy your new wall-wife.