# Why haven't I seen any ghasts in the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't know if it only happens to me but I can only find pigman. Could it be a bug or certain seeds don't spawn ghasts?

I've tried looking for them around the nether and have not found any.

FYI - My server.properties option for monster spawn is set to true. No peaceful mode is off and it's a SMP map.

How could that happen?

**SCREENSHOT AS REQUESTED**

[image]
[image]

So as you can see only pigman in sight.

Comment: Peaceful mode on?

Comment: Nope and I'm in a SMP map that I host.

Comment: It isn't your seed, they don't affect mob spawning. Do you have any mods?

Comment: How can **I** get that problem???

Comment: @fredley I have world guard, world edit, essentials and blocklogs

Comment: Are you using Bukkit?

Comment: I knew of one case where someone set a server option in the server.properties file, and then overwrote it later in the file.  Want to upload that for good measure?

Comment: Start building a precarious walkway over lava. In my experience, ghasts will suddenly show up just to spite you.

Comment: Perhaps you have a bug I have had this and after about a week it was infested with ghasts in my world but yeah Mabey it's the seed!
Hope I could help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Get out in the open

Start digging tunnels and look for a BIG AREA (the ones that involve *lots of lava*).

[A Ghast can spawn in a small area](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21188/how-much-space-is-required-for-a-ghast-to-spawn/21191#21191) but the chance is very small compared to a big area...

[image]

Comment: Im in a big area

Comment: @Warface: That's not really constructive, can you upload a screenshot/world?

Answer (score 1):

If you generated the world before the 1.2 patch, there is a chance of them spawning above bedrock, assuming you have been there.

Comment: Right, any areas of the world generated later than this, however, will not follow this rule.

Answer (score -1):

Use command /gamemode 1 for creative. Then dig a ditch into netherrack until you fall into a lower story of the Nether. ghasts usually like to spawn lower. If you accidentally fell into The Void, you dug too far down. And if you fell into the void, you need to dig up then. Just use your creative mode flying ability to fly up to the ceiling. Then just keep holding space and when  you reach a room, stop and go forawrd. If lava is flowing in your way, just dig a tunnel over the lava or just swim up the lava since you're in game mode 1. I hope this helped you a lot.

Comment: If you look at the screenshots, they are already low enough and in an open enough area, so this advice doesn't apply.

Answer (score -4):

its either your difficulty, or you don't have any room.

Comment: First of all, he's not in Peaceful. The evidence is that there are zombie pigman, which are affected by Peaceful difficulty. Second of all, there's already and existing answer accepted which mentions space a ghast spawns.