# How can the taint spread?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I spawned near a huge section of taint, and I'm fairly sure it's spreading.  My panicking in [the Minecraft chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk) turned up the suggestion of turning off the spreading in the config file, so I dug out Thaumcraft.cfg, and found this:

```
# The chance per block update (1 in n) of the Taint biome spreading. 
# Setting it to 0 prevents the spread of Taint biomes.
I:biome_taint_spread=0
```

So...it seems like it's *not* spreading?  Now, either I'm going crazy or there's something else causing it to spread.  Could Tainticles and the like (tainted spiders, creepers, etc) cause it to be spreading?

In what ways can the taint spread?

Comment: Ya know this is one of the best questions I have read about minecraft in quite some time.. +1 to you sir!

Comment: Creepers around the taint... sounds pretty bad if you ask me.

Comment: For some reason I thought it's related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-can-i-keep-monsters-out-of-my-nether-regions .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are any blocks marked to be infected they will turn to taint even after you disabled it in .cfg,but they won't spread afterwards.So make sure you **give it enough time** to really stop spreading before you declare yourself crazy.

Check your .cfg for "**aura.Taintspawn**" some people say you need to disable this but to me it looks like it is only a different name used for same setting,probably from older version.

**Bodies of water** (rivers,lakes,sea...) can't become tainted,but the taint as the infection can spread through them ; meaning,if you have 2 islands where only one of them is tainted,after enough time both of them will end up tainted.The taint will grow as it usually does through the water blocks,you just can't see it until it emerges on the surface somewhere else.In shallow waters sometimes you can see it spread on the seabed.

Even if you manage to completely stop the spreading of taint you can still infect the land by yourself using **vials** with taint,magic **cauldron**...or any similar **pollutants**.

If **Tainted Creeper explodes** outside tainted area,it will make even large crater and will also corrupt some blocks.

**Tainted Testificates** release gas that can make some tainted areas grow even more.

**Tainted Sheep** can vomit taint.

Comment: Uh oh. I didn't know about the rivers/bodies of water. That sounds bad.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly happens when the taint meets bodies of water? I'm still trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Here,I expanded the water part a bit...should make more sense now.

Comment: @Arremer Any chance this answer can be updated for Thaumcraft 4? My question (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174493/how-do-you-spread-taint-in-thaumcraft-4) apparently doesn't jive with some, so I've been sent here.

Comment: I'd like to but since I haven't played it i can't tell anything for sure.Looking up online I came up with just more rumors.
But the cauldron should still work,if you let it boil over and don't clean it up for a period of time it should taint the ground.