# How do you spread taint in Thaumcraft 4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

*Note: There's several answers on SE on how best to spread taint already, but none appear to pertain to Thaumcraft 4 specifically, with the old solutions being incompatible.*

So, for the purpose of sabotage, experimentation, etc. How does one spread taint, or create a taint zone in Thaumcraft 4?

Comment: @Rapitor Unfortunately, this merely details the mechanics of the spreading, rather than intentionally spreading it. I've already tried saturating an area with an overloaded crucible to no avail.

Comment: @Rapitor Additionally, the mention of "vials of taint" suggests this doesn't relate to Thaumcraft 4, much like the Tainted Discoveries reserch from 2: http://thaumcrafttwo.wikia.com/wiki/Tainted_Discoveries#Concentrated_Taint

Comment: The thing about questions is that they're supposed to withstand the test of time.  The question itself doesn't specify a version, so I feel your question is encompassed by the original.  I encourage you to add a comment asking for an update for the latest version.

Comment: @Frank While that might be ideal on a Q&A board, it's unrealistic in the face of software regression and other version-specific oddities that arise over time.

Still, I'll try pinging people in the other question.